# storing data in collection or list

Tags: jquery, devextreme

I need some help related to collection or list.
The requirement is that I am having a two dxdatagrid(Devexpress Widgets) with N number of records and similar column(Employee_Id) in both the grids.I want to store secont grid value in the collection,So that if I am  trying to delete any of the row from the first dxdatagrid it should check for the matching Employee_Id in the collection, and if it exist then it should show a alert message that "U can't delete the data"  else "Sucess".

Is it possible to do using jquery or devextreme.
please help me to short this out.

Answer (score 1):

When you first create/traverse the data, populate a local array in javascript. And before deleting check whether the record exists.

Start:

```
_DataStore = [];
```

When traversing:

```
_DataStore[_DataStore.length] = item.Key;
```

For checking:

```
var exists = _DataStore.indexOf(value) > -1;
```

Disclaimer: This is just a rough design, you can tweak/optimize it with your reqiurements.

Comment: Can you please explain the same with an example in fiddler.Since I am new to this    so it will be  easy for me to understand.

Comment: @vishal you'd need to post some code that you have written. The solution will totally depend on what is available for you to use.